# O que significa callback.call no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu procurei por todo lugar mas não encontro uma definição exata.

Segue minha função e o trecho do meu HTML onde é criado o DropDownList:

```js
function carregaSubCategoria(valor) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/parceiros/subcategoria/lists-subcat',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      id: valor
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',

    success: function(data) {
      var $teste = $('#subcategoria');

      $teste.empty();
      $teste.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", '').text('Selecione'));
      $teste.each(data, function(value, key) {
        $teste.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("oi errado");
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="div_categoria">
    <label class="label-control">Categoria</label>
    <select name="ofe_cat_id" id="ofe_cat_id" class="form-control" onchange="carregaSubCategoria($(this).val())">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
            echo "<option value='".$categoria->cat_id."'>".$categoria->cat_nome."</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="div_subcategoria">
    <label class="label-control">Subcategoria</label>
    <select name="subcategoria" id="subcategoria" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <?php foreach ($subcategorias as $subcategoria) {
            echo "<option value='".$subcategoria->sub_id."'>".$subcategoria->sub_nome."</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Segue uma parte do arquivo JSON:

```json
[  
   {  
      "sub_id":2,
      "sub_cat_id":3,
      "sub_cod":"00020002",
      "sub_nome":"Terror",
      "sub_desc":"Filmes de Terror"
   },
   {  
      "sub_id":3,
      "sub_cat_id":3,
      "sub_cod":"00030003",
      "sub_nome":"Aventura",
      "sub_desc":"Filmes de Aventura"
   }
]
```

Estou tentando executar esse código, mas continua me trazendo o erro:

> TypeError: callback.call is not a function

Comment: Você pode postar um trecho do seu arquivo JSON e um trecho do seu HTML que contenha o seu tag com `id` "subcategoria"?

Comment: Pronto, adicionado.

Comment: E um trecho do arquivo JSON?

Comment: Aonde está sendo chamado `call`? Provavelmente se refere a `Function.prototype.call` que é uma função nativa do javascript e está disponível em todas as funções

Comment: O `call` é de um Jquery que peguei, de um layout ja pronto, para ativar algumas classes de boostrap.

Comment: JSON adicionado também

Comment: Então adicione esse jQuery que pegou, afinal a origem do problema é nele

Comment: Por hora eu comentei a chamada do jQuery de todo o site (o arquivo tem mais de 10mil linhas de código), o problema parou, e os DropDownLists estão funcionando, mas em troca, algumas funcionalidades do layout foram desfeitas. Eu sou novo na área e não entendo muito, mas acho que é mais fácil eu montar um layout e um jQuery próprio do que tentar configurar todo esse arquivo, não??

Comment: tenta assim:
      
$teste.each(function(value, key) {
        $teste.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
      });